# Android WebView doesn't save games state

Tags: java, android, webview

I had one problem with my app. WebView in my app doesn't save score results in some HTML5, Flash games (only in few of them). But Browsers and my IOS App it automatically do. I really don't what's the problem.

```
web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
web.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
      CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(web, true);
 } 
else {
     CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
 }
 web.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
 web.loadUrl(site);
```

Comment: if you want I can provide an example of site

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem:

```
       web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            web.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            web.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(web, true);

        }
```